# Was bedeutet "Sprachverrohung" im Deutschen?

Tags: meaning

Den Begriff gibt es weder im Duden noch anderswo. Mich interessiert dabei vor allem der Unterschied zwischen *Sprachverrohung* und *Sprachverfall* und wo eigentlich diese Sprachverrohung in der deutschen Sprache zu sehen ist

Comment: Ein Wort kann nicht zugleich etwas bedeuten, und etwas anderes genau bedeuten. Was im Krimi als Mord bezeichnet wird könnte von Juristen anders bezeichnet werde. Oder was Oma im Gegensatz zu einem Wetterexperten unter Sturm und Orkan verstehen geht sicher auseinander. Das macht die Sprache des Wetterexperten wahrscheinlich genauer, aber die Wörter sind so ungenau, wie sie nun mal sind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sprachverfall: weniger gute Nutzung der zur Verfügung stehenden Wörter, z.B. Verwendung von Fremdwörtern, Denglisch, Abkürzungen und Smilies.

Es gibt auch gegenteilige Untersuchungen, wie z.B. [in *Die Zeit*, "Chats belegen das Gegenteil von Sprachverfall"](http://www.zeit.de/digital/internet/2013-01/chat-sprache-forschung).

Sprachverrohung: steigende Anzahl und im Jugendalter einsetzende Verwendung von Begriffen, die mit Gewalt in Verbindung stehen, z.B. Schimpfwörter, Drohungen, Beleidigungen.

Mein Sohn (7, 1. Klasse) wirft z.B. schon mit dem Ausdruck "verficktes Arschloch" um sich, das ich meinerzeit erst im Gymnasium zu hören bekam.

Comment: Zur *Sprachverrohung* gehört denke ich neben der tendenziellen Zunahme von Schimpfwörtern auch die tendenzielle Abnahme von Höflichkeitsformen. "Könntest du mir x geben?" -> "Kannst du mir x geben?" -> "Gibst du mir x?" -> "Gib mir x!". (Das ist kein *Sprachverfall*, denn alle Formen sind normale Teile der Sprache. Nur ihr Verhältnis untereinander verschiebt sich.)

Comment: Satz 1 zählt 4 Differenzierungen auf. Das kann schwerlich als Sprachverfall betrachtet werden. Dagegen würde ich Entdifferenzierung durchaus als solchen bezeichnen, etwa wenn viele Eigenschaftswörter (wohlschmeckend, hübsch, fetzig, preiswert, modern, ...) auf eines reduziert werden (cool, fett) in dem nur die Wertung (positiv) übertragen wird.

Comment: (1/2) @Annatar das Beispiel ist äußerst Diskussionbedürftig. Ein "Könntest du mir die Marmelade geben?" - Konjunktiv II. Das klingt nicht nach Verzweifelung oder Pessimismus, wer den Irrealis gebraucht um am Frühstückstisch nach Marmelade zu fragen der hat eine ausgewachsen Depression! Kein Wunder das so eine Person auch keine Zeit für Höflichkeiten hat und das *bitte* auslässt. Ja, hier ist nicht die Frage nach Sprachverrohung zu stellen, sondern die nach Gesellschaftsverrohung!

Comment: (2/2) Welch Gesellschaft läst es zu das dessen Mitglieder derart zu grunde gehen, dass sie solche Formulierungen in diesen Fällen verwenden? Welch humanitären Krisen setzt die Entstehung von sprachlichen Problemen vorraus wie z.B. nicht mehr zwischen der höflichen Frage das Marmeladenglas zu überreichen und Spott gegenüber dem eigenem Kind das sich gestern beide Arme verstaucht hat unterscheiden zu können (Kannst du mir das Marmeladenglas geben?)? Wir leben wahrlich in grausamen Zeiten...

Comment: @ikadfoanhfda Äh.. was?

Answer (score 2):

Eine Überlegung, die der (an sich in ihrer Kürze schönen) Beschreibung von Thomas Weller vielleicht noch hinzuzufügen wäre:

Man sollte unterscheiden zwischen "Sprachverrohung" und "Sprachverfall" als konkreten Phänomenen (deren realweltliche Existenz damit postuliert wird) und "Sprachverrohung" und "Sprachverfall" als diskursiven Konzepten, also als gedanklichen Konstrukten, die eingesetzt werden, um etwas über die Welt zu behaupten, auch wenn es vielleicht 'real' nicht nachweisbar ist.

Warum eine solche spitzfindige Unterscheidung? Weil oft, wenn früher alles besser und die Jugend noch wohlerzogen war, weniger ein realweltliches Phänomen dahintersteht als mehr ein Narrativ, das von einer bestimmten Generation erzeugt wird, oft vor allem zum Zwecke der Selbstvergewisserung. War Jugendsprache früher weniger roh? Fand Rohheit vielleicht nur in anderen Formen statt? In Kreisen, zu denen wir keinen Zugang hatten? "Verficktes Arschloch" sagten wir in der Tat nicht, als wir sieben waren, aber "Sexbombe" habe ich damals durchaus gehört (ausgesprochen in beleidigender Absicht, und altersgemäß meist mißverstanden als "Sechsbombe", also Bombe, die sechs mal explodieren kann). Was ist nun roher? Woran misst sich das?

Würfe also jemand ins Gefecht, Sprachverfall und Sprachverrohung seien evidente Phänomene, würde ich dem den Schild der Skepsis entgegenhalten.

Comment: Wie wird *Sexbombe* heute wahrgenommen? Vermutlich nicht als besonders roh, womöglich nicht einmal als beleidigend. Wie wäre demgegenüber "früher" das *verfickte Arschloch* angekommen? Vermutlich eher nicht als "harmloser" als dies heute der Fall ist. Natürlich sind dies nur zwei Datenpunkte, sodass sich keinesfalls eine allgemeingültige Aussage ableiten lässt, aber ich würde dieses Beispiel eher als Beispiel *für* als *gegen* die Annahme einer tatsächlichen Sprachverrohung einstufen.

Comment: Ich kenne Sexbombe nur als bewundernd ausgesprochene, positive Qualifizierung. Wie sich aus 6x explodieren können eine Beleidungsfunktion ergibt erschließt sich mir nicht. Außerdem bitte ich zu erklären, was die doppelten Anführungsstriche um "Sprachverrohung/-verfall" aussagen sollen, und was die einfachen um "real".

Comment: @userunknown. - Auch mir war die Verwendung des Worts "Sexbombe" als Schimpfwort gegen Mitschüler in der Grundschule (ähnlich wie "Arschloch") damals schleierhaft. Gleichwohl gab es Kinder aus dem nahen Arbeiterviertel, die das verwendeten. Über die semantischen Verschiebungen, die dem zugrundegelegen haben müssen, haben wir uns damals leider nicht ausgetauscht. - Zur Verwendung der einfachen und doppelten Anführungsstriche: Doppelte stehen hier für "Hier geht es um das Lexem", einfache stehen für "Ich räume ein, dass der Begriff problematisch ist".

Comment: Naja, das wird ja durch "als Phänomen" und "als Konzept" bereits sprachlich markiert, und so ist es doppelt markiert - man wittert eine weitere Ebene die es nicht gibt. Die Erzählstimme bleibt die gleiche, daher wirkt es nur störend. Ebenso hat das "vielleicht" das Konzept der Idee vom Diskurs des Nachweises bereits erheblich erschüttert. Das "real" hätte man also auch weglassen können, wenn man eh nicht weiß, was man damit sagen will. Insgesamt geht die Frage an der Antwort vorbei und belästigt einen nur mit kompliziertem Pseudojargon.

Comment: Erst behauptest Du umständlich, dass es beides gibt. Dann, dass man Phänomen und Diskurs voneinander trennen muss. Dann, dass die Diskurse vielleicht von etwas handeln, was es gar nicht gibt, was im Widerspruch stünde zur ersten Behauptung. Dann heißt es, eine bestimmte Generation würde die Begriffe zur Selbstvergewisserung einsetzen. Das "oft" suggeriert jedoch, dass es eben keine bestimmte Generation ist, sondern dass das die meisten Generationen tun. Dann wird die Eingangsthese unterminiert, dass es wirklich Verrohung und/oder Verfall gibt. Buzzwordbingo.